# Find Node Operation in Kadelmia: why does it pick elements from bucket instead of looking through the entire routing table?

Tags: dht, kademlia

The first step of the find node operation is as follows (as described in the [paper](http://css.csail.mit.edu/6.824/2014/papers/kademlia.pdf)):

> The lookup initiator starts by picking α nodes from its closest
> non-empty k-bucket (or, if that bucket has fewer than α entries, it
> just takes the α closest nodes it knows of).

Why does it pick the elements directly from the bucket, as opposed to looking for `k` closest elements across all elements in all buckets? I believe the latter is what happens in step 2 of the algorithm, and can be seen in the [visualization](https://kelseyc18.github.io/kademlia_vis/lookup/) here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this is simply under the assumption that α ≤ k. Under that condition you will get the k closest nodes automatically from the closest bucket, or if the bucket contains fewer than α nodes the bracketed condition will apply

> (or, if that bucket has fewer than α entries, it just takes the α closest nodes it knows of)

Also note that you're looking at the pre-proceedings version of the paper, which does not contain the full kademlia description. You can find the full paper [here](https://pdos.csail.mit.edu/%7Epetar/papers/maymounkov-kademlia-lncs.pdf).